# Python Web Scraping using "requests" Help Required

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

I want to extract data of URL of https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/exchange-traded-funds-etf. This URL extract data into tabular stock market data. Starting with columns

```
Symbol
Underlying Assets
Open
High
Low
...
...
52W H
52W L
Today
```

My objective is to get this data into Pandas Dataframe including headers

I have written following code

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

url="https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/exchange-traded-funds-etf"
headers = { "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.137"}

r=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r.status_code

# df1=pd.DataFrame().from_records(r['data'])
```

But I do not know how to proceed further, for another link from same website I used following code

```
rl="https://nseindia.com/api/equity-stockIndices?index=SECURITIES%20IN%20F%26O"

headers = { "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78"}

r=requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
df1=pd.DataFrame().from_records(r['data'])
```

But requests.get(url, headers=headers).json() it is not working for this URL. Can you pl help me to get data into Dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: You are not specifying what is your problem. Are you having issues fetching the data or parsing the data?

Comment: I do not know how to get tabular data generated by various js scripts into Dataframe. Hopefully I am clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As apw-ub mentioned, your code works fine if you use the API url. Here's the complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
import requests
import json

url='https://www.nseindia.com/api/etf'
headers = { "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.163 Safari/537.36 OPR/67.0.3575.137"}
r=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(json.loads(r.text)["data"])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks it is working. Can you pl tell me r=requests.get(url, headers=headers).json() why it was not working ?

Comment: Because you were using the wrong URL. That's it. What you wrote will work fine if you use the API url. Using (https://www.nseindia.com/api/etf) you can use: r=requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(r["data"])

Comment: Thanks undrestood, but curious to know how did you find out nseindia.com/api/etf is correct URL because when I opened URL it is showing nseindia.com/market-data/exchange-traded-funds-etf only.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, should load string JSON data with the "json.loads" function.

```
json_format = json.loads(response.text)
df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(json_format["data"])
```

Edit: Just realised your example works also, had a closer look and you can use this URL to get what you want https://www.nseindia.com/api/etf

Comment: Hi, Thanks I want to load tabular output data into Dataframe. I try to test your solution it is giving an error r=requests.get(url, headers=headers)
r.status_code
r.text
json_format = json.loads(r.text)

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\json\decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Hi Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Thanks undrestood, but curious to know how did you find out https://www.nseindia.com/api/etf is correct URL because when I opened URL it is showing https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/exchange-traded-funds-etf only. I missed out your correct URL answer below.

Comment: You can do a quick check to see if they're pulling data from an API by inspecting the page. I'm doing this on Chrome so what I did was: Ctrl + Shift + I to inspect element, access the Network tab, refresh the page, sort by type (xhr) and look for something resembling the data through the Preview tab in the sub-window, in this case "etl" is the source. This is fortunately a very straightforward example, many other websites will require configuring more extensive GET/POST requests as well as triggering JavaScript functions.

Comment: Thanks @apw-ub, understood what you want to explain, but when I do inspect element I could not file "etf" as source, for e.g. equity-master xhr I could find only Request URL: https://www.nseindia.com/api/equity-master
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 Can you tell me where I am missing out, once again thanks for educating me.

Comment: If you cant see it in the market data page try refreshing or Ctrl + R in inspect element. "etf" is just the name of the file/resource. Which so happens to contain the raw data for the exchange-traded-funds web page, i.e. the nseindia.com/market-data/exchange-traded-funds-etf page fetches and loads in nseindia.com/api/etf (as well as other things from other locations like images, css styles, other data from it's api) to build an attractive and functional page. Not every page will load in "etf". "equity-master" is also raw data, like "etf", which some other page will be fetching and loading in.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and patience to explain me in detail